# java - return an instance of a class (array)

Tags: java, android, class, object, fragment

So I have an array of classes:

```
Class<?>[] classes;
```

And I populate that classes in my constructor:

```
public Sample (Class<?>[] classes){
this.classes = classes;
}
```

Then, I have a method that returns an instance of one of the classes depending on their index:

```
public Object getInstanceOfClassWithIndex(int index){
   return new classes[index];
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work and causes a compile error.  Thanks.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How could he have a stack trace if it's a compile error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the [newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) method to create an object of the class at a given index.

```
return classes[index].newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you have an unnecessary `new` here:

```
return new classes[index];
```

try with:

```
return classes[index];
```

Mind that this returns a `Class<T>` and not a new instance of `T`. To generate it you need to use reflection through `newInstance()`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
public Object getInstanceOfClassWithIndex(int index){
   return new classes[index];
}
```

with:

```
public Object getInstanceOfClassWithIndex(int index){
   return classes[index];
}
```

You're not creating a new instance, so no `new` is required.